# Drawing new data from KDE scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sample, kdeplot

I am fitting a Kernel Density Estimation instance on multi-variate data using scikit-learn implementation. As parameters I am using a 'gaussian' kernel and  as bandwidth estimator 'silverman'

- .fit() is used to fit KDE on training data
- .sample(n_istances) is used to generate n new data points from the distribution

However, i have noticed that many of the values generated are outside the ranges of the original variables. As example, i attach the output of the code used. where, i compare ranges from original training data and newly generated datapoints.

```
kde = KernelDensity(kernel = kernel, bandwidth= 'silverman').fit(data)
print('dat:',data)
examples = kde.sample(n_istances, random_state=0)
```

[Each tuple represents a variable, where:  index column, min variable, max variable and average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS2mS.png)

Imagine this, behaviour replicated to n dimensions since i am working with many variables. Its problematic. Is there a way to select a random sample from the distribution that allows to have data within the ranges of my original ones?

Comment: Did you try other bandwidth approaches? silverman might be overestimating it or possibly estimating it correctly... did you check the deviation in the training data? Or better yet, other bandwidth estimation/ manual approaches?

Comment: I did not calculate deviation from the data..something i could do. however, the choice of bw selector on silverman relies on some assumptions which I do not know if are respected or not, but it should be more robust than Scott. Since the method I developed is meant to be runned on different datasets, its impractical to choose manually a bw.

Comment: You should maybe check your dataset for outliers, adequate number of samples for the data, and so on. Better yet, can you please include a sample of your data in your question, so we can reproduce the problem? Currently, I'm just trying to exclude the obvious stuff with comments